# Computationally solving bodies that push and pull

Tags: forces, free-body-diagram

Is there a way to find a solution for the positions (as a function of time) of multiple free bodies that push and pull on each other?

Say for instance I have a collection of cells which can individually contract or expand, and are joined to one another. For simplicity, I'm assuming two dimensions; no gravity, friction, or other external forces; and the cells are circular, and therefore connect at a point. When a cell contracts or expands, it simply reduces or increases its radius, respectively. When it contracts, it pulls on any cells that are attached to it. When it expands, it pushes on any attached cells, and in both cases it does so with a particular force. The mass of each cell is known.

I suspect this may be related to an N-body problem (perhaps even more difficult) and therefore cannot be feasibly solved exactly. If that's the case, can anyone suggest any approach for reasonably approximating this system?

Comment: Find the equation for the velocity of each body as a function of time and the positions and velocities of all the other bodies. Then decide on initial conditions for each body. Then use an RK4 method to numerically solve it. It will be an intensive process. It's not impossible, just take a long time for large N

Comment: Don't nail me down on this, but for a non-holonomic problem like this, you may have to use D'Alembert's principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle. I don't know the correct approach to a numerical solution, though, but I would suspect, that it's both well analyzed and far from trivial.

Comment: @CuriousOne far from trivial indeed. Not often implemented because of how costly it is to add each successive body to the problem. But it would work nonetheless to varying degrees of accuracy

Comment: @Jim: I would worry quite a bit about error propagation, especially with touching spheres, even more so, if one attempted to model elastic properties of the shells or the bulk. Aren't the folks who are analyzing foam-like systems doing these kinds of calculations? Is there a simplifying theory for, at least, some averaged properties?

Comment: Now we're beyond my expertise. I doubt there's a simply theory, but I could be wrong. All I know is whenever an N-body problem pops up in my work, everyone says it's not important enough to be worth the effort to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to formulate the mathematical model for this system. Once you have differential equations describing the behavior of these objects (cells) then you can time-integrate these equations on a computer; the only question is how many objects you want to include in the calculation - the more the bigger computer you'll need. My guess is that a few tens of cells can be handled today by a laptop, if you need hundreds or more then probably a large parallel machine is needed to make it a practical calculation. This problem is not a bad as the N-body problem because here it sounds like only forces between nearest neighbors are important, this makes it easier. Anyway, one thing that we know is the Newton law - if you have forces acting on an object then you know its acceleration hence you can find its velocity and position. However, what you need to specify is what is the force between two objects, if you know their positions and radii. And, for this problem you need to describe the time-evolution of the cell radius - how it depends on the forces acting on the cell etc. All this needs to be formulated as differential equations; but once this is done then solving it numerically is relatively straightforward. To get some feel what this calculation may look like I suggest keeping initially the radii of the cells constant, and use some simple potential to approximate the force between cells that are touching each other, and use some simple time-integration algorithm like the leapfrog method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration